# Orchard Workflows: display value of checkbox in email

Tags: orchardcms

I have a workflow that sends an email when a contact form is submitted.

The form contains a checkbox (`chkYesNo`), but the value when the email is sent is blank.

I have tried the following variations:

```
{Request.Form:chkYesNo}
{Request.Form:chkYesNo.checked} 
{Request.Form:chkYesNo.value}
```

Plus both upper and lowercase variations, but neither display any value in the email?

Any help much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using dynamic forms?

Comment: Yeah - dynamic forms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the syntax for form tokens is `{FormSubmission.Field:*}` where * is the field. So it would be `{FormSubmission.Field:chkYesNo}`

Comment: Thanks @Hazza. Also, I didn't realise you needed to set a 'Value' for the checkbox in your form. Without that you don't get anything regardless of how you try to access it. Incase that helps anyone else...